# Time-series data manipulation: Adding columns based on unique categories in data using python

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, time-series, data-processing

I am working on a data set of employee database which contains employee records for each quarter and therefore I ended up having each employee name multiple times. I need to pre-process the data in the form of Table 2 to train my model.

Table 1:

```
Time Stamp Emp_ID  Emp_Name   Role   Job-Level Joining-Date Exp_in_Current Role(Months)

3/31/2014   987943   John     Analyst   JL3           1/1/2014        3 
3/31/2015   987943   John     Lead      JL4           1/1/2014        2 
3/31/2014   987926   Alex      Lead      JL4           1/2/2013       13 
3/31/2015   987926   Alex      Manager   JL5           1/2/2013     2
```

I need to process the above table in the following format:

```
Employee_ID Employee_Name  Role_1   Duration in Role_1   Role 2 Duration in Role 2(As on today) 
987943       John           Analyst      12              Lead                           31 
987926       Alex            Lead        24            Manager                     31
```

Could you please help me in resolving the above mentioned problem?

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried?

Comment: @mooeeeepThis is not a homework. I am working on project on my own, and i am not able to do it as I am new python.

Comment: Does everybody have 2 jobs? If there are people with more or less jobs, it will be easier to have 1 line per job per person normally. ([tidy data](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/jfp/entry/Tidy_Data_In_Python?lang=en))